# MonoTouch table cell was not re-used (DequeueReusableCell)

Tags: xamarin.ios

Update1: heaps thanks for Greg Munn & Json to look at my code, at current stage, i think it may caused by the fact i am using the evaluation version of MonotTouch.

Update2: I pasted the version info, and the output has been update as well.

Update3: after i installed the monotouch 2.0, i was able to deploy the app to device, it does happen on the real device. but it continues to same symptom on simulator.

I got the custom class (TableSource) which derives from UITableViewSource, I found as soon as i try to scroll the table view in the simulator(6.1), it will create entire 1000 cells.  i am still trying the monoTouch, i am not sure what's the behaviour once it runs on real device. I really don't know why it create 1000 cell when i try to scroll the tableview. Am i missing something?

Here is part of the output:

```
Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format("Created: {0} Reused: {1} - currentRow: {2}", this._totalRowCreated, this._totalRowReused, indexPath.Row.ToString()));
```

- 2013-02-20 17:43:16.638 TableViewTest[3039:c07] Create new row999
- 2013-02-20 17:43:16.638 TableViewTest[3039:c07] Created: 1000 Reused: 0 - currentRow: 999
- 2013-02-20 17:43:16.638 TableViewTest[3039:c07] Create new row1000
- 2013-02-20 17:43:16.639 TableViewTest[3039:c07] Created: 1001 Reused: 0 - currentRow: 1000
- 2013-02-20 17:43:21.581 TableViewTest[3039:c07] Create new row11
- 2013-02-20 17:43:21.582 TableViewTest[3039:c07] Created: 1002 Reused: 0 - currentRow: 11
- 2013-02-20 17:43:30.650 TableViewTest[3039:c07] Reuse row1001
- 2013-02-20 17:43:30.650 TableViewTest[3039:c07] Created: 1002 Reused: 1 - currentRow: 1001
- 2013-02-20 17:43:30.651 TableViewTest[3039:c07] Create new row1002
- 2013-02-20 17:43:30.651 TableViewTest[3039:c07] Created: 1003 Reused: 1 - currentRow: 1002
- 2013-02-20 17:43:30.904 TableViewTest[3039:c07] Create new row12
- 2013-02-20 17:43:30.904 TableViewTest[3039:c07] Created: 1004 Reused: 1 - currentRow: 12
- 2013-02-20 17:43:30.905 TableViewTest[3039:c07] Create new row0
- 2013-02-20 17:43:30.906 TableViewTest[3039:c07] Created: 1005 Reused: 1 - currentRow: 0

  ```
  public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
  {
      this.window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
      this.window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

      this.viewController = new TableViewTestViewController();


      this.viewController.View.Frame = new RectangleF(
              0, 
              UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame.Height, 
              UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame.Width, 
              UIScreen.MainScreen.ApplicationFrame.Height);

      this.window.RootViewController = viewController;

      return true;
  }
  ```

---

```
private TableSource _tblSrc;

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
  base.ViewDidLoad();

  // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  if (this._tblSrc == null)
  {
    this._tblSrc = new TableSource();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
      this._tblSrc.DataItems.Add(string.Format("Row {0}", i));
    }

    this.TableView.Source = this._tblSrc;
  }
}

//---------------------------------

namespace TableViewTest.Models
{
    public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        private string _cellIndentifier = "MyCellId";
        private List<string> _dataItems;
        private int _totalRowCreated = 0;
        private int _totalRowReused = 0;

        public TableSource()
        {
        }

        public List<string> DataItems
        {
            get{ return this._dataItems ?? (this._dataItems = new List<string>());}
        }

        public override int RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, int section)
        {
            return this.DataItems.Count;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(this._cellIndentifier);

            if (cell == null)
            {  
                this._totalRowCreated ++;
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Create new row" + indexPath.Row.ToString());
                cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, this._cellIndentifier);
                cell.Tag = indexPath.Row;
            } else
            {
                this._totalRowReused ++;
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Reuse row" + indexPath.Row.ToString());
            }

            Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format("Created: {0} Reused: {1}", this._totalRowCreated, this._totalRowReused));


            var value = this.DataItems [indexPath.Row];
            cell.TextLabel.Text = value;

            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
MonoDevelop 3.1.1
Installation UUID: 4098f059-8936-47d8-8e66-4e501f33a58b
Runtime:
  Mono 2.10.9 (tarball)
  GTK 2.24.10
  GTK# (2.12.0.0)
  Package version: 210090011
Apple Developer Tools:
   Xcode 4.6 (2066)
   Build 4H127
Xamarin.Mac: Not Installed
Monotouch: 6.0.10 (Evaluation)
Mono for Android: Not Installed

Build information:
  Release ID: 30101000
  Git revision: 5d928ec4f9d5864b4db04a1301b8a8649b43fb9d
  Build date: 2012-12-14 19:11:30+0000
  Xamarin addins: 80f2dcc8fe4ed316b3e77dde496fc33d90305047
Operating System:
  Mac OS X 10.8.2
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide a little more information. I tried your code in a sample and it reused the cells as expected.

Comment: i was using evaluation version of monotouch, and iOS 6.1 simulator. when it runs, i use mouse to scroll down, then, it creates 1000 cells.

Comment: This is basically what I did, which works for me. What happens when you debug GetCell?  The output I get with this code is "Created: 12 Reused: 65" and so on.

Comment: really appreciate your help. I have uploaded the code, if you have time, please have a look.  [link](http://sdrv.ms/1510yqP)

Comment: I ran your sample, I get a 12 cells created and ~1000 reused after scrolling for a bit.

Comment: Added more code;  I am still getting 1000 cell created.  2013-02-19 04:53:41.460 Example_Data[1722:c07] Created: 1016 Reused: 16
2013-02-19 04:53:41.461 Example_Data[1722:c07] Reuse row27
2013-02-19 04:53:41.461 Example_Data[1722:c07] Created: 1016 Reused: 17
2013-02-19 04:53:41.461 Example_Data[1722:c07] Reuse row28
2013-02-19 04:53:41.462 Example_Data[1722:c07] Created: 1016 Reused: 18

Comment: I don't think using the Trial version should cause this behavior.  Are you using the latest version of MT and the Mono runtime, as well as the latest iOS SDK?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded and installed monotouch 2 days ago. i should have all the latest version. BTW, i have upload the code [Link](http://sdrv.ms/1510yqP). Would you mind to run it in the simulator. Thanks heaps.

Comment: I already did, see my comment above.

Comment: I get the same as Jason, just checking here - do you get the same result with the sample you posted? I notice that your output that you showed is for a different application. Could it be possible that the 2 aren't exactly the same.

TableViewTest[11737:c07] Created: 12 Reused: 585   --  If they are the same I'd suggest emailing Xamarin support the sample and tell which version of MT and Mono you have, they may be able to replicate the issue.

Comment: it's very strange, when i tried to create more than 2k rows, it only create 1k row, then, it start to reuse the cell.